# Move and rename files with the single command

Tags: command-line, cmd, command, batch-processing

I am looking for single command in CMD which will allow me to rename and move files from one directory to the other directory. Here is my task: Rename all .txt files in the TEST folder with the new extension .doc and then move them to the TEST2 folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is such a command. Microsoft named it `move`. See `move /?`

Comment: I tried the move command but it won't work the way I want it. I want to change the extension .txt to .doc of all the files at once while moving from one directory to the other directory, but maybe I did something wrong. Would you be able to give me an example then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ren "c:\test\*.txt" "*.doc" & move "c:\test\*.doc" "c:\test2\"
```

Comment: On linux/mac terminal


```mv oldName.js newName.js && mv newName.js src/
```

Answer (score 17):

Though its an older thread, posting this answer in case someone comes looking...

```
move "c:\test\originalfile.txt" "c:\NewLocation\UpdatedFile.txt"
```

Comment: how to move file with rename? i mean how to rename source file if it copy already exist in destination folder?

Comment: So not only can `ren` move files while renaming them, but also `move` can rename files while moving them? That's interesting. Does any of both work with relative paths?